# Using Regex to define hostname

Tags: python, regex, netmiko

I am working on a script that looks at the hostname of a device and based on this aplies geographical config.  It is currently working using a script I found online.

```
DEVICE_NAME = net_connect.send_command('show version')
HOSTNAME = re.search(r'(\S+)\suptime', DEVICE_NAME, re.M).group(1)

if re.search('ttreda.|tteu.+', HOSTNAME):
    TIMEZONE = 'GMT 0 0'
    SUMMERTIME = 'BST recurring'
else:
    TIMEZONE = 'EST -5 0'
    SUMMERTIME = 'EDT recurring'
```

But I'd like to make it a bit neater by just using show run | include hostname.
I found this search string but it fails

```
DEVICE_NAME = net_connect.send_command('show run | include hostname')
HOSTNAME = re.search(r'(\S+)\shostname', DEVICE_NAME, re.M).group(1)
print(HOSTNAME)
```

This raises the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: What is in `DEVICE_NAME`? At any rate, if there is a chance there is no match, check if there is a match first, then access `.group(1)`

Comment: Ok, so on  device if I run show run | include hostname.
The output is:
hostname ciscosw1

Comment: So, the name is to the right of `hostname`. Thus you need to match it either on the right or on the left of `hostname`, right?

Comment: Yes thats right, it will always be on the right of the word hostname

Comment: Then you need `re.search(r'hostname\s+(\S+)', DEVICE_NAME).group(1)` if you know there will always be a match. If there can be no match, consider checking for a match before accessing `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `hostname` will always come *before* the word you need to extract, you need

```py
match = re.search(r'hostname\s+(\S+)', DEVICE_NAME)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Note it is always better to check if a match occurred *before* accessing the `group(1)` value to avoid the *`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`* issue.

Note you do not need the `re.M` option as it only modifies the behavior of the `^` and `$` anchors in the regex, and yours has neither.